# Magento 1.x core config values in mysql upgrade?

Tags: magento-1, core-config-data

I have the following lines to get a core_config_data value in a mysql upgrade script

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$adapter = $installer->getConnection();

$my_store = Mage::getModel("core/store")->load("my_store", "code");
$templatePath = 'foo/bar';
$config_value = Mage::getStoreConfig($templatePath, $my_store);
```

if I debug $config_value I get null. However if I add this to a controller action I get the expected value. So it seems that I can't retrieve a config value from within a mysql upgrade script?

Comment: Is the output of $my_store correct?

Comment: @Black yes it is as expected showing the correct store